# Certificates issued to X not signed by correct authority

Tags: windows-7, trusted-root-certificates

An issue is arisen such that EVERY certificate which is being signed by any website (eg: facebook.com google.com, mail.live.com) are all issued by an unknown authority: Easy Tech, whereas I know for a fact that google is signed by itself (Google Web Authority) and facebook is signed by Verisign Inc.

I have gone into certmgr.msc and found the EasyTech certificate and rebooted the machine but still there is issues with it.

[image]

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RJMQ.png) is the screenshot of my left: my computer in the UK with the correct certificates, and right being the problematic EasyTech signed

The question is: how do you stop this from happening and what caused it?

Comment: First of all, DO NOT use that machine to do anything sensitive until this is resolved - this looks very much like a man-in-the-middle attack of some sort, and the connection is NOT secure. I'm researching this now, but that was important enough to say first!

Comment: could you open a command prompt and type in `ping www.google.com` and update the question with the result please?

Comment: @Graham That's what I originally advised.

`C:\>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [173.194.34.4] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.194.34.4: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=55
Reply from 173.194.34.4: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=55
Reply from 173.194.34.4: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=55
Reply from 173.194.34.4: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=55

Ping statistics for 173.194.34.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 51ms, Maximum = 52ms, Average = 51ms
`

Comment: Thanks! `173.194.34.4` points to `1e100.net` which is a Google address (1e100 is scientific notation for 1 googol, if you're interested), so it seems that this is more likely to be isolated to the web browsers than general networking. Check the proxy configuration of the browser(s) and if nothing untoward is in there, see what happens in Incognito/InPrivate mode as this should disable browser add-ons by default. Let me know how it goes

Comment: @GrahamWager no such luck with in private browsing and no proxy settings. I managed to find the offending certificate and delete it, but it still seems to crop back up. It also happens on IE, Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You are using Easy-Hide-IP VPN from EasyTech.

Disconnect from easy Hide and it will work ok

Comment: This is plausible, but it would be useful to know *why* you think its this application, and how to hunt down and disconnect it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy-Hide-IP VPN was the cause of this problem for me.

Thank you so much for pointing that out.

I saw "EasyTech" on my security certificates.....so this post was a bell ringer.

Uninstalled it and all works perfect now. (Easy Hide never worked any way-lousy product.)